# PostgreSQL - get all integer digits from double precision field for use in to_char function

Tags: postgresql, double, precision, numeric, to-char

As stated in the [documentation of Postgres 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html) the `double precision` data type has a precision of 15 decimal digits and a storage of 8 bytes, then an integer number larger than a normal `bigint` (8 bytes) stored in a `double precision` field is approximated. Correct me if I'm wrong, I say larger than a normal `bigint` because if you try to cast this number to `bigint` you get this error:

```
select 211116514527303268704::bigint;
>> ERROR:  bigint out of range
```

When you try to convert this to `double precision` and `numeric` and compare both you find that they're the same:

```
select 211116514527303268704::numeric,
211116514527303268704::double precision,
(211116514527303268704::double precision) = (211116514527303268704::numeric);
+-----------------------+----------------------+---------+
|        numeric        |        float8        | boolean |
+-----------------------+----------------------+---------+
| 211116514527303268704 | 2.11116514527303e+20 | t       |
+-----------------------+----------------------+---------+
```

and with the `to_char()` function they return different values:

```
select
trim(to_char((211116514527303268704::double precision),'999,999,999,999,999,999,999')),
trim(to_char((211116514527303268704::numeric),'999,999,999,999,999,999,999'));
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|            text             |            text             |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 211,116,514,527,303,270,400 | 211,116,514,527,303,268,704 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

As you can see the value returned with the to_char - numeric combination is correct but the to_char - double precision loses consistency from the exponential part in `double precision` 2.11116514527303e+20

I'm not sure if it affect something but the locale of `lc_numeric` is 'es_PY.utf8'

It's completely useless to implement `double precision` in this case or it's another alternative to keep those double precision fields? That is always the preferred option, there's some type of cast to `numeric` from `double precision` that keeps all the original digits?

For additional information I have a PostgreSQL 9.0 installation running in a CentOS 6 x86-64 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that **for the purpose of the equality comparison**, the type with the higher resolution is cast to the type of the lower resolution. I.e.: in the example the `numeric` is cast to `double precision`.

Demo:

```
SELECT *
     , num = dp          AS no_cast
     , num::float8 = dp  AS dp_cast
     , num = dp::numeric AS num_cast
FROM  (
   SELECT numeric '211116514527303268705' AS num
        , float8  '211116514527303268705' AS dp
   ) t;

 num                  | dp                    | no_cast | dp_cast | num_cast
----------------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+---------
211116514527303268705 | 2.11116514527303e+020 | t       | t       | f
```

`float8` is an alias of `double precision`.
Note that for other calculations, like addition, the type with the ***higher*** resolution is the result - which is a logic necessity. (Here the result is `boolean` anyway.)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the cast from float8 to numeric gives another result, then the part that exceeds the limit of 8 bytes is never recovered, the numeric data type is the only way to go if I want to keep all the values, correct me if I'm wrong, thanks for the very quick response!

Comment: @Osuka: You are right. `numeric` is the only data type for this  in standard Postgres.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give you an upvote when I increase my reputation